# Sum numbers which include characters in Google Sheet and App Script

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sum numbers which include characters in a range of cells, but it does not work.

Example A1 = `54%` , A2 = `10%` , A3 = `22%` .....

this is my formula :

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"\d+\.?\d+$|\d+") or =REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3,"\d+\.?\d+$|\d+")
```

But it is not working.

Is there any exact formula for that? I want result like this: `77%`

Comment: First of all, if your values are actually stored as numbers, then you do not need to do anything fancy. You can just do this: `=sum(A1:A4)`. The values `54%`, `10%` and `22%` will be summed correctly - with the percent sign included: `86%`.

Comment: If that does not work then you need to tell us more about the data in your cells - how it was populated, and what text/number format the data has.

Comment: For example, if your data values are text, then you can covert them to numbers and sum them using this array formula: `=to_percent(arrayformula(sum(value(left(A1:A3,len(A1:A3)-1)))/100))` - but it's guesswork without more information. Or, you can use a script.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumPercent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let s =0;
  vs.forEach(e => s += e * 100);
  Logger.log(s + '%')
}
```

This works too:

```
function sumPercent() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let o = vs.reduce((a,v) => {a.s += v * 100;return a;},{s:0,sum:function(){return this.s + "%"}}).sum();
  Logger.log(o);
}
```